# Angular / Karma testing of component returns undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write an angular test for a small reusable component that when clicked emits an event to replicate a button click on the DOM yet the component is coming back undefined

The Test report also seems to say the second test scenario is uncaught with a nullinjector and that  could not find an object to spy upon for onExportClicked()

**Testing code is this:**

```
import { ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ImportExportComponent } from './import-export.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../../../shared.module';

describe('ImportExportComponent', () => {
    let component: ImportExportComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ImportExportComponent>;

    beforeEach(
        waitForAsync(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [SharedModule],
                declarations: [ImportExportComponent]
            })
                .compileComponents()
                .then(() => {
                    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ImportExportComponent);
                    component = fixture.componentInstance;
                });
        })
    );

    it('should create the component', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should trigger export event emitter when button is clicked', fakeAsync(() => {
        spyOn(component, 'onExportClicked');
        const button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
        button.click();
        tick();
        expect(component.onExportClicked).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
});
```

**Component code is this:**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'utc-import-export',
    templateUrl: './import-export.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./import-export.component.scss']
})
export class ImportExportComponent {
    @Output() exportClicked = new EventEmitter<null | File>();

    constructor() {}

    // Emits an event triggering export in parent component
    onExportClicked(): void {
        this.exportClicked.emit();
    }
}
```

**Component HTML is:**

```
<button class="dropdown-item" 
type="button" 
(click)="onExportClicked()">
{{ 'LABELS.EXPORT' | translate }}
</button>
```

Any help or explanation as to why this is happening would be really useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it does not go into the `.then` block to create the `component` and `fixture`.

Try this:

```
beforeEach(
        waitForAsync(() => {
            // !! Make sure you see this log first.
            console.log('In the first beforeEach');
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                // !! Get rid of SharedModule, maybe it is causing problems
                // Your component doesn't need it.
                // imports: [SharedModule],
                declarations: [ImportExportComponent]
            })
                .compileComponents();
        })
    );

    beforeEach(() => {
       fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ImportExportComponent);
       component = fixture.componentInstance;
       // Make sure you see this log second and the component is defined.
       console.log('In second beforeEach. The component is: ', component);
    });

    it('should create the component', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

The 2nd test looks good but it seems that your component is not being constructed correctly.

Comment: I actually realised it's because of another service called within the HTML that I had to provide which was causing the component not to get to the initialization point but I appreciate your answer!